# Где в телефоне найти SQL базу данных?

Tags: android, sqlite, android-studio

Пишу приложение на android в Android Studio с базами данных. Запускаю на телефоне.
Где я могу найти в телефоне файл базы данных?

Comment: во внутренней памяти: data/your.app.id/...